# converting CSV to nested Json

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, data-structures

Please help me!! I am still learning data structure and
I am trying to convert this CSV file

```
key,a,b,c,d,e
key_01,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
key_02,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
key_03,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
```

to Json format. I have tried this script

```
   import csv
   import json

    csvFilePath = 'my.csv'
    jsonFilePath = 'my.json'


    def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
        data = {}

with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
    for rows in csvReader:
        key = rows["key"]
        data[key] = rows


with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
    jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

   make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

But the output has key row in it

```
 {
"key_01": {
    "key": "01",
    "a": "apple", 
    "y": "100.0", 
    "c": "cow", 
    "d": "doll", 
    "e": "elephant"
}, 
"key_02": {
  "key":  "02",
    "a": "apple", 
    "y": "100.0", 
    "c": "cow", 
    "d": "doll", 
    "e": "elephant"
}, 
 }
```

I want my final output to be look like this. Is there any way to make this right? Please help me.

```
{
"key_01": {
    "a": "apple", 
    "y": "100.0", 
    "c": "cow", 
    "d": "doll", 
    "e": "elephant"
}, 
"key_02": {
    "a": "apple", 
    "y": "100.0", 
    "c": "cow", 
    "d": "doll", 
    "e": "elephant"
}, 
"key_03": {
    "a": "apple", 
    "y": "100.0", 
    "c": "cow", 
    "d": "doll", 
    "e": "elephant"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this part of your code:

```
for rows in csvReader:
    key = rows["key"]
    data[key] = rows
    del data[key]['key'] # Add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict.pop` to remove the desired value:

```
import csv
import json
from io import StringIO

new_str = """key,a,b,c,d,e
01,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
02,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
03,apple,100,200,doll,elephant
"""

data = {}
csvReader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(new_str))
for rows in csvReader:
    key = rows.pop("key")
    data[key] = rows
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "01": {
        "a": "apple",
        "b": "100",
        "c": "200",
        "d": "doll",
        "e": "elephant"
    },
    "02": {
        "a": "apple",
        "b": "100",
        "c": "200",
        "d": "doll",
        "e": "elephant"
    },
    "03": {
        "a": "apple",
        "b": "100",
        "c": "200",
        "d": "doll",
        "e": "elephant"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` library if you have access to external libraries. It makes this task very straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

# We don't read the key column.
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", usecols=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])

# We create another column here with your desired format.
df["indexer"] = [f"record_{i}" for i in df.index]
# We make it the index, so if you export it to JSON later it will have your desired format.
df.set_index("indexer", inplace=True)

jsn = df.to_json('my.json', orient="index")

# OR, directly to Python dict for further use
dct = df.to_dict(orient="index")
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But I just need it put  "record_01" something like this. It was my fault not writing clearly and make it look like an index. Is there any way to do it so? ;'(